AutoHotKey Help - Creating a macro for the mouse scroll wheel using the onscreen keyboard
I'm trying to help out my disabled friend who cannot use a physical keyboard or mouse to play a new game. The reason he needs help, is because the game does not yet have the option to rebind the scroll wheel to keyboard characters, so he can zoom in and out. He uses the on-screen keyboard (OSK) to play. I created a very simple AHK script to scroll in and out, and it works, but only using my physical keyboard. When I test it using the OSK, it doesn't. I am guessing it's because the OSK is the focused window, not the game.
The script is as follows:
9::
send {WheelDown 1}
return

0::
send {WheelUp 1}
return


Essentially, hold 9 to scroll down, hold 0 to scroll up. In the game, this zooms in and out (with physical keyboard).
Anyone able to help with this? It'd be very much appreciated!
